# 私はあおい車はすきだ (は as contrast particle) vs 私はあおい車がすきだ

Tags: particle-は

I am learning about は particle that is used as contrast particle. suppose I want to express "I like blue car but I don't like any other colors". can I say it this way `私はあおい車はすきだ` ? and what's the difference with `私はあおい車がすきだ` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, exactly. Both sentences are perfectly grammatical, but 私は青【あお】い車は好【す】きだ implies you don't like cars which aren't blue, because the contrast particle は is used at the place where が is normally used. 私は青い車が好きだ simply means "I like blue cars."

Comment: so if we use が the speaker is trying to say he like blue car but it means there is a chance the speaker also like any other colors or he doesn't like any other colors at all?

Comment: @Kakashi It depends. If you use が, It's plain "I like blue cars". You may or may not like red ones. Using は is like saying "I like *blue* cars" ("blue" part stressed).

Comment: ありがとう先生! crap it seems i chose wrong username this time.